# How to support multiple user pools in Amplify Cognito for flutter?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-cognito

There are 2 configurations in AWS, first one to support email/password sign in, the second for Google SSO. If I add on my Amplify configuration the OAuth info for using the Google SSO it works, but when trying to come back the session is gone.

I need to be able to have the configuration for the 2 user pools, rigth now my config json looks like this:

```
final _amplifyConfigSSO = '''
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
                "Version": "0.1.0",
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                    "Default": {
                        "PoolId": "${Environment.ssoCognitoPoolId}",
                        "AppClientId": "${Environment.ssoCognitoAppClientId}",
                        "Region": "${Environment.ssoCognitoRegion}"
                    },
                },
                "Auth": {
                    "Default": {
                      "OAuth": {
                            "WebDomain": "${Environment.ssoCognitoWebDomain}",
                            "AppClientId": "${Environment.ssoCognitoAppClientId}",
                            "SignInRedirectURI": "${Environment.ssoCognitoOAuth}",
                            "SignOutRedirectURI": "${Environment.ssoCognitoOAuth}",
                            "ResponseType": "code",
                            "Scopes": [
                                "email",
                                "openid",
                                "profile"
                            ]
                        },
                        "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH",
                        "socialProviders": [
                            "GOOGLE"
                        ],
                        "usernameAttributes": [
                            "EMAIL"
                        ],
                        "signupAttributes": [
                            "EMAIL"
                        ],
                        "passwordProtectionSettings": {
                            "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
                            "passwordPolicyCharacters": [
                                "REQUIRES_LOWERCASE",
                                "REQUIRES_UPPERCASE",
                                "REQUIRES_NUMBERS",
                                "REQUIRES_SYMBOLS"
                            ]
                        },
                        "mfaConfiguration": "OFF",
                        "mfaTypes": [],
                        "verificationMechanisms": [
                            "EMAIL"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}''';
```

and for login I'm using this code:

```
Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito.pluginKey).signIn(
  username: username,
  password: password,
);
...
Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito.pluginKey).signInWithWebUI(
  provider: AuthProvider.google,
);
...
```

So far, I have tried to add the `OAuth` section on the config allowing the app to do the Google login, but when the app is restarted the user does not exists anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved this by storing locally the token, id, and refresh token with `flutter_secure_storage`, then using the OAuth web service from Cognito to validate the token.